# How to make graph with 4 Y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I want to make a graph with 4 Y axis. I know how to make dual Y axis graph but I am not able to make the graph with 4 y axis.I have included one example of dual Y axis graph.someone, please help me in this dual y axis graph to make 4 y axis graph.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you did for two axis.

define 4 axis in yAxis section and in series section specify which data goes into which axis.

```
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: false,
        title: {
            text: 'third Axis'
        }
    }, {
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: false,
        title: {
            text: 'fourth Axis'
        }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        data: [44.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 116.4, 180.1, 195.6, 154.4, 129.9, 72.5, 108.4, 159.2],
        yAxis: 2
    }, {
        data: [ 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1,129.2],
        yAxis: 3
    }]
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/v4ortcm7/) is a sample fiddle for you